# HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mp3" is not supported

Tags: firefox, html5-video

I run mediaelement on Firefox then Firefox throw error message below

"HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mp3" is not supported. Load of media resource xxxxxx

Please Anyone help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't this really be audio/mp3?

Comment: Maybe reading the docs help to solve your problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLMediaElement ?

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type for mp3 is not **video/mp3** it is **audio/mpeg**.You can refer to media types [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_audio)
.

If you want to play a MP4  file then it must be **video/mp4**.You can check more media types for video [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_video)

You can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements) for media types supported by Firefox.

Comment: This says nothing about which content types firefox actually supports. Also how do you know that this is an mp3 resource?

Comment: @hakra yes you are right. I have edited the answer to accommodate both audio and video content types.

Comment: Please check your link. You're both times linking wikipedia that is about some mime-types in general, but gives no insight which content-types firefox in specific supports. The error message in the question is from firefox.